# GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl throws AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am writing a module in C# which needs to retrieve the effective rights on a resource for a given Active Directory user account. I'm attempting to pinvoke the [GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-geteffectiverightsfromaclw) C function to do this. The function is returning an exception:

`System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

From my extremely limited knowledge of unmanaged programming, I'm lead to believe that maybe one of the pointers I'm passing into the function (or the TRUSTEE struct) isn't actually pointing to the place in memory that I think it does.

Here's my code:

```cs
class Program {
    const Int32 NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE = 0;
    const Int32 TRUSTEE_IS_SID = 0;
    const Int32 TRUSTEE_IS_USER = 1;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern UInt32 GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(
        IntPtr pAcl,
        ref TRUSTEE pTrustee,
        ref Int32 pAclRights);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
    struct TRUSTEE {
        public IntPtr pMultipleTrustee;
        public Int32 MultipleTrusteeOperation;
        public Int32 TrusteeForm;
        public Int32 TrusteeType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public String ptstrName;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var SID = new WindowsIdentity("company\user1").user ?? throw new ArgumentException("User does not exist");
        IntPtr fileACLHandle = getFileSecurityHandle("C:\temp\test.txt"); //Confirmed working via the pinvoked GetNamedSecurityInfo C function

        var trustee = new TRUSTEE {
            pMultipleTrustee = IntPtr.Zero,
            MultipleTrusteeOperation = NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE,
            TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
            TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
            ptstrName = SID.Value
        };

        Int32 pAclRights = 0;
        UInt32 result = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(fileACLHandle, ref trustee, ref pAclRights);
        if (result != 0) {
            Int32 hResult = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            var ex = new Win32Exception(hResult);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return;
        } 

        Console.WriteLine($"Rights: {pAclRights}");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That issue is usually from some P/Invoke declaration being not quite right. Take a look at http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl.html. That site is your friend when P/Invoking system calls

Comment: Please show how you declare and initialize `keySecurityHandle`

Comment: In [TRUSTEE_W](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/accctrl/ns-accctrl-trustee_w) (which, btw, appears to be wrong / mistyped), `ptstrName` is declared as `LPWSTR`, so you either marshal a string as `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` or declare it as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()` -- As mentioned, not clear where `keySecurityHandle` comes from and what `fileACLHandle` is then for

Comment: @Flydog57 Actually, I had originally copied the P/Invoke declaration directly from pinvoke.net, but when I tested it that way, I was getting everyone's favorite "The parameter is incorrect". It seems like I'm getting a step farther with my current declaration.

The other problem is that this article doesn't specify how to declare the TRUSTEE struct, which seems a bit complex.

Comment: @NineBerry - `keySecurityHandle` is an artifact from before I sanitized this code for SO. I've updated the code; thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Jimi - Thanks for the catch. I corrected `LPTStr` to `LPStr` in my `TRUSTEE` struct declaration. Same issue persists, however.

Comment: When you get it working, don't forget to update the PInvoke.net article to make it easier for the next person

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was my lack of understanding about marshalling pointers between managed and unmanaged memory. I had a method, which I didn't post because I didn't think it was relevant, that was returning an `IntPtr` handle, however, I was destroying the handle in that same method!

```
static IntPtr getHandle(Byte[] bytes) {
    IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, handle, bytes.Length);
    //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle); <-- Destroys the pointer! Don't do this yet.
    return handle;
}
```

This explains the `Attempted to read or write protected memory.` message: I had freed up the memory that my handle was pointing to before I actually used it!

In terms of P/Invoke, my declaration was a bit off as well. Here is what worked:

```
const Int32 NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE = 0;
const Int32 TRUSTEE_IS_NAME = 1;
const Int32 TRUSTEE_IS_USER = 1;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct TRUSTEE {
    public IntPtr pMultipleTrustee;
    public Int32 MultipleTrusteeOperation;
    public Int32 TrusteeForm;
    public Int32 TrusteeType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public String ptstrName;
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(
    IntPtr pAcl,
    ref TRUSTEE pTrustee,
    out Int32 pAclRights);

//-----And later on-----//
Int32 pAclRights = 0;

try {
    var trustee = new TRUSTEE {
        pMultipleTrustee = IntPtr.Zero,
        MultipleTrusteeOperation = NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE,
        TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
        TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
        ptstrName = userName
    };

    Int32 hResult = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(keySecurityHandle, ref trustee, out pAclRights);

    if (hResult != 0) {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //do something with the exception
} finally {
    //Lastly, deallocate the unmanaged pointer
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(keySecurityHandle);
}
```

The final thing I should point out is that I was doing extra work to translate a user ID into a SID. It is far easier to pass a userID, which the `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` function is able to resolve in virtually any format.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of issues with your code.

- Structure packing (in general, you should not specify it, defaults are consistent between .NET and Win32)
- Ansi vs Unicode
- Error handling (GetLastError is not used by these APIs)

Here's a version that seems to work:

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // get some identity

var status = GetNamedSecurityInfo(@"c:\temp\file.txt",
    SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
    SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SECURITY_INFORMATION.UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    out var fileACLHandle,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    IntPtr.Zero);
if (status != 0)
    throw new Win32Exception(status);

var nameTrustee = new TRUSTEE_WITH_NAME
{
    TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_FORM.TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
    TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_TYPE.TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
    ptstrName = identity.Name
};

status = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(fileACLHandle, ref nameTrustee, out var accessMask);
if (status != 0)
    throw new Win32Exception(status);

Console.WriteLine($"Rights: {accessMask}");

var sid = new byte[identity.User.BinaryLength];
identity.User.GetBinaryForm(sid, 0);

var sidTrustee = new TRUSTEE_WITH_SID
{
    TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_FORM.TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
    TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_TYPE.TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
    pSid = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(sid, 0)
};

status = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(fileACLHandle, ref sidTrustee, out accessMask);
if (status != 0)
    throw new Win32Exception(status);

Console.WriteLine($"Rights: {accessMask}");

...

public enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
{
    SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE,
    SE_FILE_OBJECT,
    SE_SERVICE,
    SE_PRINTER,
    SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
    SE_LMSHARE,
    SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
    SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
    SE_DS_OBJECT,
    SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
    SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
    SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
    SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY
}

[Flags]
public enum SECURITY_INFORMATION
{
    OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001,
    GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000002,
    DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004,
    SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000008,
    UNPROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x10000000,
    UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x20000000,
    PROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x40000000,
    PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = unchecked((int)0x80000000)
}

public enum MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE_OPERATION
{
    NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE,
    TRUSTEE_IS_IMPERSONATE
}

public enum TRUSTEE_FORM
{
    TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
    TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
    TRUSTEE_BAD_FORM,
    TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID,
    TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_NAME
}

public enum TRUSTEE_TYPE
{
    TRUSTEE_IS_UNKNOWN,
    TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
    TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP,
    TRUSTEE_IS_DOMAIN,
    TRUSTEE_IS_ALIAS,
    TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP,
    TRUSTEE_IS_DELETED,
    TRUSTEE_IS_INVALID,
    TRUSTEE_IS_COMPUTER
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct TRUSTEE_WITH_NAME
{
    public IntPtr pMultipleTrustee;
    public MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE_OPERATION MultipleTrusteeOperation;
    public TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm;
    public TRUSTEE_TYPE TrusteeType;
    public string ptstrName;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TRUSTEE_WITH_SID
{
    public IntPtr pMultipleTrustee;
    public MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE_OPERATION MultipleTrusteeOperation;
    public TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm;
    public TRUSTEE_TYPE TrusteeType;
    public IntPtr pSid;
}

[DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetNamedSecurityInfo(string pObjectName, SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType, SECURITY_INFORMATION SecurityInfo, IntPtr pSidOwner, IntPtr pSidGroup, out IntPtr pDacl, IntPtr pSacl, IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);

[DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(IntPtr pacl, ref TRUSTEE_WITH_NAME pTrustee, out int pAccessRights);

[DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(IntPtr pacl, ref TRUSTEE_WITH_SID pTrustee, out int pAccessRights);
```

Comment: Your code sample is really informative and exhaustive.  Although, I think most folks would expect to see the `DllImport`, structs and enumerations on top rather at the end.  That threw me off. When you pointed out the issues with my code, your explanations were a bit too short & obtuse to have much value for me. Now that I've had a better look at your example code, I would like to change my vote, however it is locked right now. I will return.